# Alpha value in removing gravity from acelerometer data

Tags: android, math, accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors

I came across this solution to remove gravity values from raw values of an acelerometer but I can't understand why `alpha = 0.8` and not just 0.997.

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
 {
      // alpha is calculated as t / (t + dT)
      // with t, the low-pass filter's time-constant
      // and dT, the event delivery rate

      final float alpha = 0.8;

      gravity[0] = alpha * gravity[0] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[0];
      gravity[1] = alpha * gravity[1] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[1];
      gravity[2] = alpha * gravity[2] + (1 - alpha) * event.values[2];

      linear_acceleration[0] = event.values[0] - gravity[0];
      linear_acceleration[1] = event.values[1] - gravity[1];
      linear_acceleration[2] = event.values[2] - gravity[2];
 }
```

Comment: what is the initial value of gravity[i]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comment on your code: alpha = t / (t + dT), so alpha is just to be calculated according to your filter time lenght and the sampling rate of the accelerometer.

if your solution sets alpha = 0.8 it simply means that dT = 0,025 t or, on the other side, t = 40dt.

If you increase the sampling rate of the accelerometer, decreasing dT you'll have alpha pointing asyntotically to 1.

Comment: So having my sampling rate at 100 Hz and time length equal 30 seconds... I'm kind of new in filtering.

Comment: sorry didn't see your comment. If you set sampling rate at 100Hz, means dT = 1/100s = 10ms. So with t = 30secs, alpha will be 30/(30+0.01) = 0.999, that is actualy "almost" 1 as said.

Comment: @CristianoZambom shouldn't t be the time constant meaning 1 s?

Comment: no..the time costant of a filter means the "speed" of the filter answer. If you have a filter with a T time costant, and you have a step to value 10 as input (I.e. a function that is always 0 until the time instant 0, and always 10 after), the filter will answer with an exponential wave asyntotically pointing to 10, reaching the 66% of its final value (10*0x66 = 6.6) after T seconds.

Comment: In other words, if you set a time constant of 30 seconds  in your system filtering the axelerometer, and you accelerate the system on Z-axis constantly with an axeleration of i.e. 1m/s^2, you will see the Z output of your filter giving you the 66% of the 1m/s^2 after 30 seconds, and the right final value approximately ater 3T = 90secs.

Comment: well, my signal time is not 30s, my window size is 30 seconds. so it means T is the signal total length?

Comment: as stated in the remark at the beginning, T is the low pass filter time-constant. Watching the code you posted, this is simply applying a low pass filter to the input signals (events.values[n]) and the substracting the output of the filter to the signals theirself. That means that all variations faster than (about) 30secs will be filtered by the filter, and so not substracted to the signals value. This is good for the gravity filtering, as gravity is fortunately not willing to change rapidly :)

Comment: so T time-constant has no relation with your window size. As you can consider the gravity a constant, the choose of the T that fits your need depends on what kind of accelerations you have to measure: with T = 30seconds, all accelerations that last for less than (about) 30 seconds will be filtered. You can imagine T as the speed of your system in answering to input stimuli. As gravity can be considered a constant, you could significantly decrease you T still removing with success the gravity signals.

Comment: With alpha = 0.8 and a sampling rate of 100Htz, you have T = 40 dT, that means that all accelerations lasting for more of (about) 40 samples will be seen on the outputs values. That means, at 100Htz, that you will see acceleraton lasting more than 0.025s, 25ms. If you can plot a graph of the values you get out after filtering (linear_acceleration[n]), and you shake your device while plotting you will see that the bigger T you choose, the longer must be an acceleration to be seen by the filer.

Comment: you are welcome...by the way, the sentence "you will see acceleraton lasting more than 0.025s, 25ms" is wrong, sorry for that. Exactly, 40dT at 100Htz is 40*10ms = 400ms, not 25.